# Closed form or simplification of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^{n-k}(1-x^k)}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, power-series, harmonic-numbers

Does there exist a simpler form of

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{n-k}(1-x^k)}{k}$$

For $x \in ]0,1[$. Perhaps some combinatorial interpretation?

Comment: Hint: use $x^{n-k}(1-x^k)=x^{n-k}-x^n$.

Comment: @xpaul. I've started in that direction, but I can't find a closed formula

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the sum as $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{n-k}(1-x^k)}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{n-k}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^n}{k}= x^n \left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{-k}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k}\right]$$

And use the fact that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{k} = H(n)$$ where $H(n)$ is the Harmonic number.

Also note that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{x^{-k}}{k} = \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{n+1}\left[-\Phi\left(\frac{1}{x},1,n+1\right) \right]-\log \left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)$$

where $\Phi(x,s,a)$ is called the [Lerch transcendent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html), as per list of known identities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume you forgot a minus sign when introducing the integral?

Comment: @fawadria Yeah, right.

Comment: I'm stuck at your last step though. If you expand the sum again, you will simply end up with your original expression right?

Comment: @fawadria Which step?

Comment: The last integral containing $(1+x+x^2+\ldots)$. If you evaluate this integral, you end up with the same sum you were trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: @fawadria Yeah you are right. Check my edit.

Comment: @AliShather Thanks for pointing out the error. I have tried to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Expression of the form$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{x^k}{k}$, can be rewritten as $\int_{0}^{x}\sum_{k=1}^{n}y^{k-1}dy$. You can sum (up to $n$), adn then take the integral. Keep in mind $\int \frac{dx}{1-x} = -\log(1-x) +C$

Comment: Is it possible that these integrals don't solve properly? I have expressions containing incomplete beta functions

Comment: The integral exists everywhere except $x=1$

Comment: Well I was hoping for a nice expression, but I don't think there exists an easy solution. See for example this solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415630/series-summation-of-geometric-harmonic-series