Find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{400}\frac{n+1}{n(2^{n})}$.
Find the value of the following summation :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{400}\frac{n+1}{n(2^{n})}$$
Now if I put some of the values of $n$ like $1,2,3,...$ then the following summation will be $\frac{2}{1×2}+\frac{3}{2×4}+\frac{4}{3×8}+....$ upto $400$ terms.
Now I know how to find the summation of an Arithmetico-Geometrico Progression.
For example I know how to find the summation of the sequence:
$a, (a+d)r, (a+2d)r^{2}, (a+3d)r^{3},....$
Let me show it step by step.
$S=a+(a+d)r+(a+2d)r^{2}+...+(a+(n-1)d)r^{n-1}$
$\implies rS=ar+(a+d)r^{2}+...+(a+(n-2)d)r^{n-1}+(a+(n-1)d)r^{n}$
$\implies S(1-r)=a+(dr+dr^{2}+...+dr^{n-1})-(a+(n-1)d)r^{n}$
$\implies S=\frac{a}{1-r}+\frac{dr(1-r^{n-1})}{(1-r)^{2}}-\frac{(a+(n-1)d)r^{n}}{1-r}$
But my sequence is neither an Arithmetic Progression nor Geometric Progression nor Arithmetico-Geometrico Progression.
My sequence that is $$T_{n}=\frac{n+1}{n(2^{n})}$$ is typically an example of Arithmetico-Geometrico-Harmonico Progression.
Because $2,3,4,...$ is in A.P.
Again $\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...$ is in H.P.
And finally $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},...$ is in G.P.
So, is there any formula for $$\sum_{n=1}^{400}\frac{n+1}{n(2^{n})}$$ ?
Please let me know if anyone can find it.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{400}\frac{n+1}{n(2^{n})} =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{400}\frac{1}{2^{n}} +\sum\limits_{n=1}^{400}\frac{1}{n(2^{n})}$ and the $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{400}\frac{1}{2^{n}}$ term is $1-2^{-400}$ but the exact value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{400}\frac{1}{n(2^{n})}$ term is not simple and could involve the incomplete beta function or hypergeometric function or polylogarithm. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415630/series-summation-of-geometric-harmonic-series

@DietrichBurde - I think it is may closer to $1+\log(2)$.

How u found the summation upto infinity @DietrichBurde ?

@DietrichBurde See Wolfram Alpha's attempt

@Henry Ah, sorry, my link is over $\frac{n+1}{n^2 2^n}$, which is different.

Thanks to Henry, I found that the infinite sum is indeed equal to $1+\log(2)$, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+1}{n2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}=1+\log(2).
$$
See for example these references (it is enough to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n}$):
Calculus II: The sum of a series
Why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}\ n} =\log (2)$?
A summation question ,Is $S \to \ln 2$?
To estimate a partial sum, say up to $n=100$ or $n=400$, see here:
Finding the difference $\log (2) - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{100} \frac {1} {2^n \cdot n}.$
